# How to show sorting indication next to a table header column - Datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, datatable

I have a datatable table.

[image]

I can't sort it base on the table header, but I want to add some indication like arrows up&down next to my table header column.

Is there a way to achive that in css or js ?

This is the settings that I have for that now.

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.10/features/searchHighlight/dataTables.searchHighlight.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.js"></script>




<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>





<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.sysEventTable').DataTable( {
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "orderCellsTop": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "Info": false,
        "bSort": true,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "searchHighlight": true,
        "dom": '<"pull-right"B><"pull-right"f><"pull-right"l>tip',
        "buttons": ['copy','csv','pdf','excel','print']
    } );

    $('#myInputTextField').keyup(function(){
        $('.sysEventTable').DataTable().search($(this).val()).draw();
    });


</script>
```